# Why is UTF-8 encoding lost after POST request?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, encoding, utf-8

I have a simple jquery ajax post cal to send some data to a server. The data contains characters in UTF-8.

Here is the code:

```
var data = {
    name: "Ländertrends"
}

var data_string = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(data_string); //encoding still looks good here

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/savedashboard.php",
    data: { saveDashboard: data_string, dashboardname: name, conf: conf },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",        

    success: function(result) {

        console.log(result);

    }
});
```

includes/savedashboard.php looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
var_dump($_POST['saveDashboard']);
?>
```

On my development server (Ubuntu 14.04, Apache2, PHP 5.5.9), the output is fine and looks like you would expect:

> string(24) "{"name":"Ländertrends"}"

However, on a second server (CentOS 6.8, Cpanel, Apache2, PHP 5.4.45), the encoding is messed up:

> string(25) "{"name":"L���ndertrends"}"

I can see the content type of the request comes back as UTF-8.

If I use mb_detect_encoding() it says the string is in EUC-JP.

My guess is that some system setting is making the difference, but which one?

I have already set the content type, also added `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to a `.htaccess` file, and added `charset="utf-8"` to my script tags, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

By the way, I can work around the problem by converting the string back to UTF-8, but I would like to know why this is happening on one server and not the other.

Comment: Is the <meta charset="utf-8"> tag set in your HTML?

Comment: what are the files' encoding saved as?

Comment: Yes the meta tag is set in the html that loads the script

Comment: they are saved as UTF-8. In reality the names with UTF chars arn't in the javascript file though, they come from a db, and that is in UTF-8 too. Remember it works perfectly on one server, just not on the second

Comment: You are pulling from the same database server? On both Dev and Prod? Or is there a separate mysql instance.

Comment: It's not the same db, but I can see the encoding is correct right before I fire the ajax call in the console.log(data_string)